# Conditions for $A=\small\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$ to have canonical form $B=\small\begin{bmatrix}\lambda&1\\ 0&\lambda\end{bmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra

What facts should I consider to prove that this is true? I know that there is some $P$ composed of eigenvalues of $A$ such that $P^{-1}BP$. Just need some direction on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case (warning: analogous larger cases could be harder) all you need is that $A$ has a single eigenvalue of multiplicity $2$.  That is, the characteristic polynomial
$$(a-\lambda)(1-\lambda)-b=\lambda^2-(a+1)\lambda+(a-b)$$
should be a perfect square, that is,
$$(a+1)^2=4(a-b)\ .$$
Note that the only diagonalisable $2\times2$ matrices with the same eigenvalue twice are scalar multiples of the identity, and $A$ is not such a matrix.

Comment: can you elaborate a little on how you determined that?

Comment: @grayQuant In general, what your condition says is that $A$ has a double eigenvalue and it is not diagonalizable. In 2 dimensions, a matrix with a double eigenvalue is diagonalizable if and only if it is already diagonal (since in this case all vectors would be eigenvectors for the same eigenvalue). Since your matrix is not diagonal, David's condition is correct.

Answer (score 2):

First, the characteristic polynomial of $A$ should have a double root $\lambda$. Second, $A$ should not be diagonalizable.